# How do I place nodes on the same level in DOT?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I want to render several trees simultaneously and place all root nodes and all leaf nodes on the same level.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do. Root nodes A and X are on the same level, and so are leaf nodes B, D, and Z.

[image: Graph I want]

I unsuccessfully tried putting roots in one rank and leaves in another as follows:

```
digraph G { 
rankdir = TB;
subgraph {
A -> B
A -> C
C -> D
X -> Y
rank = same; A; X;
rank = same; B; D; Y;
} /* closing subgraph */
}
```

And got this outcome where everything is on the same rank.
[image]

Any suggestions about what I should be trying? I've already got roots and leaves identified.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Putting the `rank = same; ...` statements in braces, e.g.:

```
digraph G { 
  rankdir = TB;
  subgraph {
    A -> B
    A -> C
    C -> D
    X -> Y
    // note that rank is used in the subgraph
    {rank = same; A; X;}
    {rank = same; B; D; Y;}
  } /* closing subgraph */
}
```

... gives the desired result:

[image]

Comment: Is the subgraph really necessary? I'm satisfied with this result:

digraph {
  rankdir=LR;
  1902387216 [label="h"];
  1902387216 -> 1736863396 [label="child"];
  1736863396 [label="e"];
  1736863396 -> 166482735 [label="peer"];
  {rank = same; 1736863396; 166482735;};
  166482735 [label="a"];
  166482735 -> 915735320 [label="child"];
  915735320 [label="n"];
  915735320 -> 1424861798 [label="child"];
  1424861798 [label="d"];
  1736863396 -> 233979847 [label="child"];
  233979847 [label="r"];
}

Comment: @WilliamJohnHolden: I agree with you that the subgraph isn't really necessary. In the original question it was probably a part of the overall graph, the rest of which was omitted to create a minimal example.

Answer (score 15):

The ideal structure is actually rank max and rank min.  No need for a subgraph or any other shenanigans.  GraphViz has explicit facilities for this.

With complex graphs, rank=same will often end up near the middle of the graph.  If you mean top and bottom, say top and bottom.

```
digraph G { 

  rankdir = TB;

  A -> B;
  A -> C -> D;
  X -> Y;

  { rank=min; A; X; }
  { rank=max; B; D; Y; }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Here's a simple example inspired by @William John Holden's comment -

```
graph {
  rankdir=LR;
  a -- b -- c;
  d -- e -- f;
  b -- d; {rank = same; b; d;};
}
```

[image: graph]